# How to tell EF that this field is in the conceptual model but not in the database

Tags: entity-framework-4

What's that attribute that you annotate your model property with to tell EF that please don't look for this field in the database and please don't map it to anything in the database. This is just in the conceptual model?

Answer (score 1):

[NotMapped]

http://msdn.microsoftcom/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx

```
namespace Models
{

  public partial class Foo
  {
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
  }

}
```